# Unexpected token inside JSON code

Tags: json, reactjs, webpack

I'm using webpack in combination with React and will load some external data from a static json file. When I use this code inside the `entry.jsx` file:

```js
const data = require('../data/data.json');
```

I've got this error:

> ```
> ERROR in ./data/data.json
> Module parse failed: C:\location\data\data.json Line 2:
> Unexpected token :
> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
>   1. | {
>   2. |     "start": 0,
>   3. |     "scenes": [
>   4. |         {
>   @ ./jsx/entry.jsx 14:26-54
> ```

Also when I use `"start": "0",` instead of the current code, I've got the same error on the same line.

Comment: Are you able to share more of the json file?

Comment: are you using `json-loader` in webpack?

Answer (score 0):

By a comment of @MayankShukla, I've solved the issue. I was missing `json-loader`. I've add this to my `webpack.config.js` file like this:

```js
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.json$/,
            loader: "json-loader!json-loader"
        }
    ]
}
```

And inside `entry.jsx` I've changed the line from my question:

```js
const data = require('../data/data.json!json-loader');
```